# how to align a page to a frame in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am rendering a page inside of a Frame. The aqua color is the background color of the frame. How can I adjust the alignment of the page to fit the frame?

[image]

Comment: Post XAML for your Frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Padding` property of the `Frame` and/or the `Page` to `0`:

```
<Page Padding="0" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Padding property of the page? 
That should be set to 0, something like

```
<Page Padding="0" ...    />
```

Comment: Hi, it was actually the "Padding" that needed to be set to 0 0 0 0, if you update your answer i will accept it